# Get Attribute from Elequent where clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

So I have the following where clause where I am searching the name "Gold" inside of my tier table.

```
$tier = Tier::where(['name' => 'Gold'])->get(['id']);
dd($tier);
```

When I do the above the "id" is listed inside of the attributes but when I do as below it gives me

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id

```
dd($tier->id);
```

All I want is to get the Id of the record where the name is "Gold".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get actual model you should use `first()` instead of `get()`. Because there are potentially multiple rows that match `get()` will return a collection.

```
$tier = Tier::where(['name' => 'Gold'])->first(['id']);
dd($tier->id);
```

If you really need only the id there's even a simpler function to that, `pluck()`.

It will get one attribute from the first result:

```
$id = Tier::where(['name' => 'Gold'])->pluck('id');
```